# Is there a way to launch phone camera app from Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

Is there a way other than creating a page with CapturePreview control inside to capture a photo with the camera and set it to an Image object. I need to launch the phone's camera instead of this http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Phone Camera" some phones have the "lumia camera", some just have a "Camera" it is simply an app which might be different in each phone, so no, there is no way to launch the camera and take a photo with it. You can however access the photo library and pick photos.

Comment: Well isnt the situation the same with Android?

Comment: Android has a camera API